# result comes out from a webmethod used in another webmethod in ASP.Net Web Services

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, visual-studio-2008

I have two Problem related with Web Services by using visual studio..

```
[WebMethod(Description = "Matrix")]
public decimal[] matrixMethod(decimal num1, decimal num2, decimal num3, decimal num4, decimal num5)
{

    decimal[] a;
    a = new decimal[5];

    a[0] = 1 / num1;
    a[1] = 1 / num2;
    a[2] = 1 / num3;
    a[3] = 1 / num4;
    a[4] = 1 / num5;

    return a;
}
```

1. How can we use result comes out from a WebMethod ("Matrix") used in another WebMethod for further calculation.
2. Is there is any way two create a dynamic text-boxes in Web Services for use input as i know in ASP.Net Web Services we have to pass a parameter in method for user input, but i want if user enter 4 then 4 text-boxes should be created and if he/she enter 8 then 8 text-boxes are created and the values entered in these text-boxes produces some result.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the result of a web service exactly like you would use the result of any other method.
2. Web services have nothing to do with text boxes. You have to do text box stuff in a web page.

Answer (score 0):

1) you can use public variables for multiple functions.

2) you can create any number of textboxes using javascript. If you need it only for storing values you can use arrays for dynamic storage.